# Laravel: how to get value from query builder object

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am new in laravel. i have a table but dont have model for this. I am using below to fetch record.

```
$classes = DB::table('school_classes')->get();
return view('classes', ['allClass' => $classes]);
```

it returns below:

```
[{"id":1,"register_school_id":1,"class":"I","section":"A","created_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00"},
{"id":2,"register_school_id":1,"class":"I","section":"B","created_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00"},
{"id":3,"register_school_id":1,"class":"I","section":"C","created_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00"},    {"id":4,"register_school_id":1,"class":"I","section":"D","created_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00"},        
{"id":5,"register_school_id":1,"class":"I","section":"E","created_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-03-19 00:00:00"}]
```

how I can pick the value separately of each item... i tried foreach but getting error.
 plz help. thanks in advance.

Comment: In Laravel, if you echo out objects, they are automatically translated to json. Try the dump and die helper `dd($allClass);` to see the real object. Make use of models. It will greatly speed up the coding of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query builder returns a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` instance. You can access the collection as below:

```
@foreach($allClass as $class)
    {{ $class->id }}
@endforeach
```

Also check [Collections](https://laravel/docs/collections)

Answer (score 0):

You want to get data in array format, then you can use "toArray" & also easily access data using foreach loop Laravel function.

```php
$classes = DB::table('school_classes')->get()->toArray();

return view('classes', ['allClass' => $classes]);
```